# Is it possible to capture a screen shot for a webelement directly by using WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

At [Interface TakesScreenshot](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/TakesScreenshot.htm) page I found this:

> Capture the screenshot and store it in the specified location.  For
>   WebDriver extending TakesScreenshot, this makes a best effort
>   depending on the browser to return the following in order of
>   preference: - Entire page - Current window - Visible portion of the
>   current frame - The screenshot of the entire display containing the
>   browser
>
> For WebElement extending TakesScreenshot, this makes a best effort
>   depending on the browser to return the following in order of
>   preference: - The entire content of the HTML element - The visisble
>   portion of the HTML element.

So I am wondering it should support capture screenshot of a webelement, but can't find any document relate to this support by now.  not sure if it really supported or not.

anybody know more details about this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation would indicate that it *is* supported, but in practice, it does not work (at least not with the .Net bindings):

```
var screenshotTaker = element as ITakesScreenshot;
var image = screenshotTaker.GetScreenshot();
image.SaveAsFile(fileName, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // << null exception thrown here
```

There is a workaround that has worked for me - execute javascript on the page to get the location of the element:

```
const string javascript = "return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect()";
var obj = (Dictionary<string, object>)((IJavaScriptExecutor)_core.Driver).ExecuteScript(javascript, element);
var rect = new Rectangle((int)double.Parse(obj["left"].ToString()),
                         (int)double.Parse(obj["top"].ToString()),
                         (int)double.Parse(obj["width"].ToString()),
                         (int)double.Parse(obj["height"].ToString()));
```

That will give you the location of the element within the viewport, at which point you can take a screenshot of the entire page and crop it down to just the bounds of the element.

Hopefully that helps...

Comment: Doesn't the WebElement class itself have methods for top, left, width, and height? Seems like the Java binding does: element.getLocation().getX(), element.getSize().getWidth(), etc. But it's good you provide this code snippet. It could be useful for language bindings that don't have that info natively.

Answer (score 1):

Following the idea of @Anders, in Java  - no javascript required (using [javaPng](https://code.google.com/p/javapng/)):

```
byte[] imageBytes = ((TakesScreenshot)webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
BufferedImage img = new PngImage().read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes), true);

//set element to the required webElement
BufferedImage crop = img.getSubimage(element.getLocation().x, 
    element.getLocation().y, element.getSize().width, element.getSize().height);
```

Comment: I sometimes run into exception like "RasterFormatException: (x + width) is outside Raster" for this type of implementation. But it doesn't happen all the time. I'm just using the element coordinates & size, so no way that can be wrong. Interestingly, no issue using other libraries like http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/javaxt.io.Image/

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Bitmap FullScreen { get; set; }
public static Bitmap Image { get; set; }

public static void TakeScreenShot(ChromeDriver driver, IWebElement element)
{
    Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();

    screenshot.SaveAsFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\screens\file.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

    FullScreen = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\screens\file.bmp");

    Size element_size = element.Size;
    Point element_location = element.Location;

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(element_location, element_size);

    Image = FullScreen.Clone(rect, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    Image.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\screens\file2.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);

}

void Main()
{
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://domain.com");

    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    IWebElement _element = driver.findElementById("ElementIdGoesHere");
    TakeScreenShot(driver, _element);
}
```

This code will take full screenshot of the page, then it will look for the `_element` location and the image will be saved to the disk using the rectangle size of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
WebElement webElement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//html")).get(0);

File screen = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(screen);

File f = new File('element.png');

Point p = webElement.getLocation();
int width = webElement.getSize().getWidth();
int height = webElement.getSize().getHeight();
BufferedImage dest = img.getSubimage(p.getX(), p.getY(), width, height);
ImageIO.write(dest, "png", f);
```

Then, after you verify this works, replace the webElement with your own element.  Run this code first just to make sure your webdriver has the screen shot capability and that your file io works as expected (ie you will discover where the files are saved).

What this does is capture a screenshot, saves it to file.  Then, reads that file as an image and grabs a subimage based on the position of the element.  Then, it saves that sub image to file.  This requires two file writes and a file read (so there would probably be a good optimization for this).