# Is it possible to set Selenium Webdriver to take a screen capture upon encountering an error

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver, screenshot

Is it possible to set up webdriver so that when an error is encountered, a screen capture can be taken?

Comment: okey, what you are looking for is already may be [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642376/is-it-possible-to-capture-a-screen-shot-for-a-webelement-directly-by-using-webdr?rq=1

Comment: Was wanting the screen shot to be taken only in the case of an error being thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, it is possible. Here is the example:

```
WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
firefoxDriver.get("http://www.google.com/");
File scrsht = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrsht, new File("your_path/screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: Is there any way of causing this code to be run upon encountering an error?

Comment: Yes, call them from catch block.

Comment: What's your import for FileUtils?

Comment: commonsIO from here - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/index.html?org/apache/commons/io/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are running JUnit, you can set up a Rule to take a screenshot on failure. There is a similar way to do this for TestNG.

**Event.java**

```
public static void takeScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String name) throws IOException {
if (driver instanceof TakesScreenshot) {
    File tempFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
            .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    FileUtils.copyFile(tempFile, new File(String.format("screenshots/%s.png", name)));
    }
}
```

**ScreenshotOnFailRule.java**

```
public class ScreenshotOnFailRule extends TestWatcher {

    private static boolean shouldStopTests = false;

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable e, Description d) {
        try {
            Event.takeScreenshot(yourDriver, "Failure");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            log.error("Test didn't finish due to hard failure.");
            shouldStopTests = true;
        }
        if (shouldStopTests) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
}
```

Then at the start of your test class:

```
    @Rule
    public TestRule screenshot = new ScreenshotOnFailRule();
```